# Cannot use breakpoint in the callback function of Socket.BeginConnect()

Tags: c#, sockets

```
    public bool Connect (string address, int remotePort)
    {
        if (_socket != null && _socket.Connected)
            return true;


        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry (address);
        foreach (IPAddress ip in hostEntry.AddressList) {
            try {
                IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint (ip, remotePort);

                _socket = new Socket (ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                _socket.BeginConnect (ipe, new System.AsyncCallback (ConnectionCallback), _socket);

                break;

            } catch (System.Exception e) {
                PushPacket ((ushort)MsgIds.Id.CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAILED, e.Message);
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    void ConnectionCallback (System.IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        NetBitStream stream = new NetBitStream ();

        stream._socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        try {
            _socket.EndConnect (ar);

            _socket.SendTimeout = _sendTimeout;
            _socket.ReceiveTimeout = _revTimeout;

            PushPacket ((ushort)MsgIds.Id.CONNECTION_REQUEST_ACCEPTED, "");

            _socket.BeginReceive (stream.BYTES, 0, NetBitStream.HEADER_LENGTH, SocketFlags.None, new System.AsyncCallback (ReceiveHeader), stream);


        } catch (System.Exception e) {
            if (e.GetType () == typeof(SocketException)) {
                if (((SocketException)e).SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionRefused) {
                    PushPacket ((ushort)MsgIds.Id.CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAILED, e.Message);
                } else
                    PushPacket ((ushort)MsgIds.Id.CONNECTION_LOST, e.Message);
            }

            Disconnect (0);
        }
    }
```

Here are two functions. When I call

```
client.Connect ("127.0.0.1", 10001);
```

It just steps over the `break;` after

```
  _socket.BeginConnect (ipe, new System.AsyncCallback (ConnectionCallback), _socket);
```

and goes to `return true;`. I set a breakpoint at ConnectionCallback but it does not go into this function.

There is no server listening on the `10001` port.

So I think it at least should throw an exception (connect failed), then go into the `catch`.

Or have I made a mistake in the two functions?

Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

```
    using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace TestSocket
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            NetTCPClient tcp_client = new NetTCPClient ();
            tcp_client.Connect ("127.0.0.1", 10001);
        }
    }

    class NetTCPClient
    {
        Socket _socket = null;
        public bool Connect (string address, int remote_port)
        {
            if (_socket != null && _socket.Connected)
                return true;
            IPHostEntry host_entry = Dns.GetHostEntry (address);
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host_entry.AddressList) {
                try {
                    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint (ip, remote_port);
                    _socket = new Socket (ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    IAsyncResult ia = _socket.BeginConnect (ipe, new System.AsyncCallback (ConnectionCallback), _socket);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Connet() catch an exception!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        void ConnectionCallback (System.IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("ConnectionCallback() ");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger doesn't work that way. With very few exceptions, it will not switch threads without explicit instruction from you.

When you are stepping through the `Connect()` method you wrote, you are debugging a particular thread in your program. The `ConnectionCallback()` method, if and when it is called (note that it is *not* generally going to be called synchronously during your call to `BeginConnect()`), will be called in a different thread. If you want to debug it, you need to set a breakpoint at or in the `ConnectionCallback()` method itself.

With a breakpoint set in that method, you are assured that the debugger will pause the execution of your program there, regardless of which thread is executing that method.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the full code example. Assuming that *is* in fact the code example you are testing with and having trouble with, then your problem is (as was already guessed) one of two things:

1. After stepping through the call to the `Connect()` method, you do not resume execution of your program. I.e. you did not click the "Continue" button or use the "Continue" menu item in the "Debug" menu. Or…
2. You do resume execution of your program, which then promptly exits before the connection attempt can be resolved.

In case #1 above, you never see the breakpoint because *your program is not executing*. The breakpoint can only be triggered if execution of the program does in fact arrive at the breakpoint. But the execution of your program can't arrive there if it's not happening at all.

In case #2 above, you never see the breakpoint because *your program is not executing*. In this case, it's because the program has exited altogether.

If you want to see the breakpoint at the `ConnectionCallback()` method get triggered, you need to let the program run, and for long enough for that to happen.

As a quick proof-of-concept, I set a breakpoint at that method, and added this statement to the end of the `Main()` method:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

I then used the debugger to step through the `Main()` method. It of course paused to let the program run at the above statement I'd just added, but then very quickly interrupted the program again, right at the desired breakpoint. (I didn't have to wait anywhere close to 5 minutes…I just used that as a very large time value that I was sure would be enough).

For what it's worth, I also tried a test where I stepped through the original `Main()`, i.e. without the call to `Thread.Sleep()`, but waited about 5-10 seconds after stepping over the call to `Connect()` before proceeding. In that case, at least on my computer, I *also* did see the breakpoint triggered. That particular test is somewhat dependent on machine configuration, so it's less reliable than adding the call to `Thread.Sleep()`. But it did work in my case.

Comment: The fact is I set a breakpoint that ConnectioinCallback() and it happened nothing

Comment: Well, _something_ should happen, eventually. It could take some time (depending on the state of the network and the timeout configuration) before an error actually occurs when trying to connect to a non-existent endpoint. How long did you wait before giving up?

Comment: And what is your program doing while you're waiting? Not still stopped in the debugger, I hope. If you don't let your program continue to run, obviously the breakpoint can't be hit.

Comment: Please leave your email, I send you the whole source codes.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how this works. If you want someone to try to reproduce the problem, you should include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the problem. Personally, my bet is that you're simply misusing the debugger; over the years I've debugged a fair amount of code, including network code, and what you're describing shouldn't happen if you're using the debugger correctly (and of course assuming the program is even still running when the connect attempt finally fails).

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have misunderstood what `BeginConnect` does. That doesn't make the connection - it just *starts* making the connection, asynchronously. So yes, I'm not at all surprised that "step over" immediately steps to the next statement - that's working as intended.

However, I *would* have expected that a breakpoint in `ConnectionCallback` would be hit - that's what you should concentrate on as a problem. That's also where you should put the exception handling, as that's where any problems with making the connection would be found.

Alternatively, if you're using C# 5 or higher, you should look into using async/await, which would allow you to get rid of all the callbacks. Then you'll get a much more familiar experience when debugging - if you step over *that* line, it really will be connected (or there'll be a failure) by the time you hit the next line. Just be aware that other things may happen (even on the same thread) while it's "awaiting" the response.

Unfortunately, I can't see anything in `Socket` which implements the relevant pattern. You could use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to adapt the "old" style to the "new" style, but it's likely to be fairly painful.

Another approach is to try to move to higher-level constructs like `TcpClient` instead of the lower-level `Socket` class.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: There's `TaskFactory.FromAsync` which will do a bunch of things for you, but I think it's better to go straight to the "designed for async/await" methods wherever possible. And yes, oops, hadn't spotted that `ConnectAsync` won't work - will remove that bit.

Comment: The fact is I set a breakpoint that ConnectioinCallback() and it happened nothing

Comment: @mingchaoyan: If you could post a short but *complete* program showing that, we could try to reproduce the problem. We don't know what the rest of your program is doing - it might have finished before the connection attempt succeeded or failed, for example...

Comment: @mingchaoyan: Your `Main` method will complete, terminating the program, before the asynchronous connection has time to finish. Add a call to `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the `Main` method (for example) and you *will* see the callback being called.